# Ignoring data when using SimpleXML to list children

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using Simple XML to format election results data into a user-friendly webpage. I'm listing the races and candidates using PHP foreach, but there's some extra data (7 elements, to be exact) nested under each race that's being treated as candidates. How can I filter them out?

Here's the XML: https://ftpcontent.worldnow.com/wicu/BTI/election.xml

Here's the code output: https://lillydigitalmedia.com/election.php

Here's the code:

```
        <?php
        $btiresults = simplexml_load_file("https://ftpcontent.worldnow.com/wicu/BTI/election.xml");
        echo "<p><em>Updated: " . $btiresults['Time'] . "</em></p>";
        foreach($btiresults->children() as $race) {
            echo "<h4 class='card-title' style='margin-top: 20px'><strong>" . $race->Name1 . "</strong></h4>";
            foreach($race->children() as $candidate) {
                echo "<p style='width: 100%;'><span style='float: left;'><strong>" . $candidate->Name . "</strong> <small>" . $candidate->Party . "</small></span><span style='float: right;'>" . $candidate->Votes . " votes</span></p>";
                echo "<div class='progress' style='height: 25px; width: 100%;'>";
                echo "<div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' style='width:" . $candidate->PercentageOfVotesCast . "%' aria-valuenow='" . $candidate->PercentageOfVotesCast . "' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'>" . $candidate->PercentageOfVotesCast . "%</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not simply check for them and do something?

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] the question to include sample XML and output _in the question itself_. Not only should we not need to click random links to help you, there's a high chance they'll stop working in future, making this question useless to other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with xml, you might as well use xpath.

Try something like the following (after the existing `echo "<p><em>Updated: " . $btiresults['Time'] . "</em></p>";`):

```
$races = $btiresults->xpath('//Race');
        foreach($races as $race) {
            echo "<h4 class='card-title' style='margin-top: 20px'><strong>" . $race->Name1 . "</strong></h4>";
            foreach($race->xpath('./Candidate') as $candidate) {                
                echo "<p style='width: 100%;'><span style='float: left;'><strong>" . $candidate->Name . "</strong> <small>" . $candidate->Party . "</small></span><span style='float: right;'>" . $candidate->Votes . " votes</span></p>";
                echo "<div class='progress' style='height: 25px; width: 100%;'>";
                echo "<div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' style='width:" . $candidate->PercentageOfVotesCast . "%' aria-valuenow='" . $candidate->PercentageOfVotesCast . "' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'>" . $candidate->PercentageOfVotesCast . "%</div>";                                
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks. This did it. I'll keep this in mind for similar situations moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply look at the tag name of the Element, using `SimpleXMLElement::getName`.

Wrap the content of your inner foreach loop into an if condition that checks if it is `Candidate`:

```
foreach($race->children() as $candidate) {
  if($candidate->getName() == 'Candidate') {
    echo '…';
  }
}
```

(Might perhaps make sense to rename the variable from `$candiate` to something like `$child`, since at the time it gets assigned a value in the foreach loop, you don’t know whether its actually a `Candidate` node yet … but that is a rather philosophical aspect.)